# Code for adding Content Controls Word 2007 C#

Tags: c#, word-2007, contentcontrol

I was wondering if anyone has any idea how I can add Content Controls to a Word Document (Office 2007) from the Document Task/Action Pane via C#.  The goal is the following:

I want to have categorized information in the Task/Action Pane and have the user fill out the info there.  Once they have filled out that information they'll click on a button and it will insert content Controls into the Word Document that has that Data.

The reason I want to use Content Controls is because the data will be bound to a database.

Is this possible?  I would like links that do this without WordProcessingML or OpenXML.  There has to be a way to do this via server side code and such that doesn't require long blocks of ,, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is great article on the subject.

[Populating Word 2007 Templates Through Open XML](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/populating-word-2007-templates-through-open-xml/)

Comment: It's best to paraphrase the important parts of the article in this answer. If that link were ever moved or deleted this answer would become useless.